# Not getting Firebase database data

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing app to display user score that store in firebase database but after running application it won't display data in listview

**below is my code:-**

```
listViewLeaderBoard = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_leader_board);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("score");

        leaderBoards = new ArrayList<>();

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    LeaderBoard leaderBoard = postSnapshot.getValue(LeaderBoard.class);
                    leaderBoards.add(0,leaderBoard);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        //Collections.sort(leaderBoards);
        CustomLeaderBoardAdapter adapter = new CustomLeaderBoardAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.leader_board_list_layout,leaderBoards);
        listViewLeaderBoard.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Database snapshot:-**

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
listViewLeaderBoard = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_leader_board);

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("score");

    leaderBoards = new ArrayList<>();

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                LeaderBoard leaderBoard = postSnapshot.getValue(LeaderBoard.class);
                leaderBoards.add(leaderBoard);
         CustomLeaderBoardAdapter adapter = new CustomLeaderBoardAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.leader_board_list_layout,leaderBoards);
    listViewLeaderBoard.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, move this line of code:

```
List<LeaderBoard> leaderBoards = new ArrayList<>();
```

inside `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will always be, due the asynchronous behaviour of this method which is called even before you are trying to add those objects of `LeaderBoard` class to the list.

Also, `leaderBoards.clear();` is no needed anymore. Your code should look something like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference scoreRef = rootRef.child("score");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String imageUrl = ds.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            long score = ds.child("score").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d("TAG", image + " / " + Urlname + " / " + score);
            list.add(image + " / " + Urlname + " / " + score);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
scoreRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: if leaderBoards.clear() method delete then it will overwrite data so it display old as well as new data.

Comment: There will be no data to be overridden at the beggning of the loop, that's why a said that. Give it a try. Does it work?

Comment: What is the error? Add a screenshot of your updated code.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error but listview is still blank, please see my updated code.

Comment: Ok, it's not working, but why? What is the error? What is the behaviour? I'm trying to help.

Comment: I don't know why it can't get data because the other listview getting data from same database and they working fine but this one not getting data in listview. and it doesn't display any error in logcat.

Comment: Have you tried my above code? The exact code that i have provided you?

Comment: Your code working fine but not showing data in listView.

Comment: Yes because your `ListView` and your `ArrayAdapter` should be defined also inside `onDataChange()` method (not in the for loop). That's why I said that  `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You can find and change the rules for your database in the Firebase console.Simply choose your project, click on the Database section on the left, and then select the Rules tab.I don't know you have done this or not try this hope this will help you.

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
}
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to store data in database with this kind of rule because it crack application data security so any user who is not authenticated also use your database. Thanks for help

Comment: you can change the rules according to your requirement plz refer to the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/

Comment: That's right Payal but if you use above rule then anybody can modify your data without permission, and I got your point but you know :)